# CentOS server not responding

Tags: centos, service

I have a CentOS 6.5 server for hosting.  It has sshd, httpd, mysqld, smtpd, dovecot, postfix, named working fine.   but since last year I updated the server to PHP 5.4, MySQL 5.5, it starts having problems.  Sometimes all services do not work except it response to ping.  I added some monitoring service from 3rd party website.  That website told me that my server reply 200 to httpd so it does not alarm me.  All I can do is ask people in Data center to reboot it.

I want to know where is the problem.   Since I cannot even use SSH to connect to server, I don't know what is the problem.  Is there any way or script to find out where is the problem?

Comment: Does your hosting provider offer out-of-band management? (Remote console?) If not, all you can do is ask they reboot.

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be looking at all log files, in particular /var/log/syslog.

Without any information my guess would be that it is an out-of-memory condition. Any service (including ssh) would stop, ping is pretty much the only service still working because it is directly handled by the kernel.

Comment: I don't have syslog in the log folder.  I only have boot.log, dmesg, maillog, mcelog, messages, secure, and some other files.  which one should I look into?   If it is the out-of-memory problem, how can I find which service used all the RAM?

Comment: I found the Mem used very fast. 

Mem:  24685044k total, 23025540k used,  1659504k free,   516436k buffers
Swap: 10223608k total,      152k used, 10223456k free, 17774752k cached

Comment: but free shows i used only 4G ram.#  free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         24106      22523       1582          0        505      17411
-/+ buffers/cache:       4607      19498
Swap:         9983          0       9983